# How can I connect to python pdb debugger running under docker + supervisord?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, supervisord, pdb

I have a Python app (Flask, but this is likely incidental) which I have Docker-ized (using Docker Compose, which is again likely incidental).  I have processes other than `python`/`flask` which need to run in the same container, and I user `supervisord` for this as it is convenient.

I set a `pdb` breakpoint `pdb.set_trace()` in my code and want to connect to my Flask app's TTY so I can interact with the `(pdb)` prompt.  This usually works fine, but I'm not usually using `supervisord`.  I can't get a reliable interactive `(pdb)` prompt - it looks like my terminal is not connected properly.

The usual steps to allow debugging (via `docker attach`) have failed me:

Telling `docker-compose.yml` to open the tty and connect stdin:

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

Telling `docker-compose.yml` to set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
```

My `supervisord` block for the process is:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:flask]
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=flask run
```

How can I work with `pdb` running under Docker and `supervisord`?

Comment: None of the solutions here worked for me. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540510/8285811) using `remote-pdb` did however.

Answer (score 2):

To get this working, I had to abandon the usual `docker attach` approach on a container running in `-it` mode ... this did not work with any combination when running under `supervisord`.

What I had to do to debug was:

1. Temporarily comment-out all four (4) of the `std???_logfile???` lines in my `supervisord.conf`.  Normally these are good for redirecting each processes' output back to `docker logs`, but they cause the loss of `pdb` output.
2. Use `supervisorctl` to access the Flask application and interact with `pdb`.

The `supervisorctl` bit in-detail:

1. Before or after your `pdb.set_trace()` breakpoint has been hit, run `docker-compose exec <servicename> supervisorctl`, or with plain Docker `docker exec -it <containername> supervisorctl`.
2. At the `supervisor>` prompt, run `fg <processname>`, using the processname of your process running Flask/Python.
3. You should get a `(pdb)` prompt when your breakpoint is hit.  You may need to issue a `(pdb)` command such as `l` to get the terminal to issue a prompt.
4. `CTRL-C` and `exit` when you are finished with `supervisorctl`.

Comment: Sometimes it may be easier to use a remote debugger:

https://github.com/Kozea/wdb
https://pypi.org/project/rpdb/